# NET8 Blazor create UI with threads

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm creating a website using `Blazor` and `NET8`. I have a few blocks calling different functions on a page. Those functions are doing different things, some calling APIs others internal functions.

To give the users a nice experience, I thought running those functions in parallel using `Task` was a good idea. When a task has completed its job, the UI can be updated. In the beginning I wrote something like this

```
await UpdateWord();
await UpdateExamples();
await UpdateSynonyms();
await UpdateAntonyms();
```

and every function at the end of the activity calls `StateHasChanged();`. It works.

Now, I try to improve this approach running the requests in parallel. To create the list of tasks, I wrote this

```
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateWord(); StateHasChanged(); }),
    Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateExamples(); StateHasChanged(); }),
    Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateSynonyms(); StateHasChanged(); }),
    Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateAntonyms(); StateHasChanged(); })
};

Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
try
{
    t.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger?.LogError(ex, "Error");
}
```

When I use this code I get the following error.

> One or more errors occurred. (The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.)

Is it make sense to use `Tasks` for different operations in the UI and improve the user exprience? If yes, what is the best practice to do that?

Comment: avoid `.Wait()`.  You can `await t;`

Comment: I'm assuming this is Interactive Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow on from HH's answer here's a demo that shows what you're trying to achieve with some timers to show execution times.  My process heavy task just calculates a lot of prime numbers.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics;

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.


<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => RunPrimesAsync(10)">Run</button>
</div>
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <pre>@_log.ToString()</pre>
</div>

@code {
    // Log of the transactions
    private System.Text.StringBuilder _log = new();

    // lock object used to ensure only one thread can write to the log at any one time.
    private readonly object LogLock = new object();

    private async Task RunPrimesAsync(int number)
    {
        _log.Clear();

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        lock (LogLock)
            _log.AppendLine($"Start Running Primes - SC Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        var tasks = new List<Task> {
            Task.Run(() => RunAsync(10, "Task 1")),
            Task.Run(() => RunAsync(1, "Task 2")),
            Task.Run(() => RunAsync(5, "Task 3"))
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        watch.Stop();

        lock (LogLock)
            _log.AppendLine($"Total Run time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisceconds");
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(int number, string name)
    {
        await this.RunLongProcessorTaskAsync(number, name);
    }

    public async Task RunLongProcessorTaskAsync(long num, string name)
    {
        lock (LogLock)
            _log.AppendLine($"{name} running on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");

        // this invokes StateHasChanged on the Synchronisation Context
        // and ensures it yields to give the UI SC time
        await InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged).ConfigureAwait(ConfigureAwaitOptions.ForceYielding);

        var watch = new Stopwatch();

        num = num * 8;
        watch.Start();
        var counter = 0;
        for (long x = 0; x <= num; x++)
        {
            for (long i = 0; i <= (10000); i++)
            {
                bool isPrime = true;
                for (long j = 2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();

        lock (LogLock)
            _log.AppendLine($"It took {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds to complete {name}.");

        // calls the more succinct wrapper method - either way works
        await UpdateUI();
    }

    // Method to encapsulate the rather long winded call to StateHasChannged
    private async Task UpdateUI()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged).ConfigureAwait(ConfigureAwaitOptions.ForceYielding);
    }


}
```

This is the completed screen.  Each line will appear as it's logged.

[image]

Comment: I like it! I think the function `UpdateUI` is not called from anywhere

Comment: No it was just to demo how to encapsulate the rather long winded Invoke async call into something a little more succinct.  StringBuilder isn't thread safe, so the locks prevent simultaneous writes.

Comment: @Enrico UpdateUI is actually called all the way at the end of 'RunLongProcessorTaskAsync'.

Comment: @Tigerware - that was because I changed the answer to show both!

Comment: Thank you @MrCakaShaunCurtis. The code is working quite well!

Answer (score 2):

Task.Run uses Threads on top of Tasks. In general you want to run asynchronous methods parallel without extra threads.

Assuming that you can move the StateHasChanged calls into the Update methods it can be done like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>
{  
    UpdateWord() ,
    UpdateExamples() ,
    UpdateSynonyms(),
    UpdateAntonyms()
};

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // run methods in parallel
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger?.LogError(ex, "Error");
}
```

Comment: @Enrico What's the result type of `UpdateXxxxx`?

Comment: Using additional threads might well be a desired usecase. You just need a way to talk back to the UI thread somehow.